# Viewing the Full JSON on a Webpage

Tags: r, json

I have this webpage over here: https://www.reddit.com/r/FunnyandSad/comments/112yfey/really_surprised_how_this_didnt_become_a_big_news/

I want to extract all comments from this website.

I learned how to do this in a previous question ([Converting JSON Lists into Data Frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75545026/converting-json-lists-into-data-frames)):

```
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


URL  <- "https://www.reddit.com/r/FunnyandSad/comments/112yfey/really_surprised_how_this_didnt_become_a_big_news/.json"

results = fromJSON(URL) |>
  pluck("data", "children") |> 
  bind_rows() |>
  filter(row_number() > 1) |>
  unnest(data) |>
  select(id, author, body) |>
  mutate(comment_id = row_number(), .before = "id")
```

**My Question:** When I look at the results, I see that only 37 comments have been collected:

```
> dim(results)
[1] 37  4
```

However, on the actual page, there are more than 1000 comments:

[image]

**Is there any way to modify the above code so that more comments are extracted - is there someway to view the full JSON?**

Thanks!

**Update:**

As per the suggestions in the comments, I tried using the "read_json" function:

```
# results[[2]]$data$children[[i]]$data$body

results = read_json(URL)

body_list <- list()
for (i in seq_along(results[[2]]$data$children)) {
    body <- results[[2]]$data$children[[i]]$data$body
    body_list[[i]] <- body
}
```

But this only returns 36 comments instead of all comments?

Comment: The comments should be nested as replies. Use read_json instead of fromJson to get pure Json.

Comment: results = read_json(URL) |>
  pluck("data", "children") |> 
  bind_rows() |>
  filter(row_number() > 1) |>
  unnest(data) |>
  select(id, author, body) |>
  mutate(comment_id = row_number(), .before = "id")

Comment: I get this error: Error in `unnest()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `data` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @ r2evans: thank you for your reply! Please see the updates: results = read_json(URL)

body_list <- list()
for (i in seq_along(results[[2]]$data$children)) {
    body <- results[[2]]$data$children[[i]]$data$body
    body_list[[i]] <- body
}

Comment: I think the problem might be that all comments arent being stored on the original page itself?

Comment: @stats_noob, I spoke too soon ... I think the code might be assuming a lot, but it isn't erring like I thought (the website is getting overloaded, I keep getting HTTP 429 errors).

Answer (score 2):

The data has a nested structure. You can do some recursive expansion with the following function

```
get_comments <- function(x) {
  if (is.null(x) || (length(x) ==1 && x=="")) return(NULL)
  result = list()
  if (is.null(names(x))) {
    for(p in x) {
      result = c(result, get_comments(p))
    }
  }
  else {
    if (x$kind == "Listing") {
      result = c(result, get_comments(x$data$children))
    } else if (x$kind == "t1") {
      result = c(result, list(x$data), get_comments(x$data$replies))
    }
  }
  if (length(result)>0) {
    result
  } else {
    NULL
  }
}

URL  <- "https://www.reddit.com/r/FunnyandSad/comments/112yfey/really_surprised_how_this_didnt_become_a_big_news/.json"
json <- jsonlite::read_json(URL)
comments <- get_comments(json)
sapply(comments, function(x) x$body)
```

But that still only returns 198 values. There are bunch of "more" blocks with just an ID where you will need to make additional API calls to get more information. See the [morechildren](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_api_morechildren) end point for more details. It looks like you'll have to authenticate to access those endpoints.

Comment: @ MrFlick: thank you so much for your answer! In the past few days, I have been trying to learn more about the official Reddit API. I posted a related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75576022/r-correctly-writing-and-converting-dates-in-utc-format Can you please take a look at this if you have time? Thank you so much!