# R: Correctly Writing and Converting Dates in UTC Format

Tags: r, json, api, date, utc

I am trying to learn how to use the Reddit API (https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps).

I registered for an account/API - **I want to retrieve 100 comments containing the word "covid" posted between March-01-2020 and March-02-2020.**

Using the documentation from the API (https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/), I ran the following R code.

First, I registered the API:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

response <- POST("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token",
                 authenticate('****', '***'),
                 user_agent("some_name"),
                 body = list(grant_type="password", 
                             username="aaaaaa", 
                             password="bbbbbbb"))

access_token_json <- rawToChar(response$content)
access_token_content <- fromJSON(access_token_json)
access_token <- access_token_content$access_token
access_token

url <- "https://oauth.reddit.com/LISTING" # try api/v1/me

authorization_bearer <- paste("Bearer ", access_token, sep="")
result <- GET(url, 
              user_agent("some_name"), 
              add_headers(Authorization = authorization_bearer))
```

Next, I tried to make a request:

```
# Set start and end times
start_time <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2020-03-01 16:52:00", tz = "UTC"))
end_time <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2020-03-02 13:52:00", tz = "UTC"))

# Set query parameters 
query_params <- list(
  limit = 100,
  q = "covid",
  #subreddit = "news", # 
  #author = "some_author", #
  after = start_time,
  before = end_time
)

# Make the API request 
response <- GET(url, query = query_params, add_headers(Authorization = authorization_header, `User-Agent` = user_agent_string))

# Extract the response 
response_json <- rawToChar(response$content)
response_content <- fromJSON(response_json)

# Extract the relevant fields 
final_result <- data.frame(
  title = response_content$data$children$data$title,
  subreddit = response_content$data$children$data$subreddit,
  author = response_content$data$children$data$author,
  created_utc = as.POSIXct(response_content$data$children$data$created_utc, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC"),
  permalink = paste0("https://www.reddit.com", response_content$data$children$data$permalink)
)
```

When I look at the results:

```
> head(final_result)
                                                                                   title          subreddit            author         created_utc
1 COVID-19 is a leading cause of death in children and young people in the United States            science thebelsnickle1991 2023-01-30 16:27:21
2                I thought Covid was a thing of the past.. double vaccinated wicked sick  mildlyinfuriating    Northeast4life 2023-02-19 00:52:03
3          ‘People aren’t taking this seriously’: experts say US Covid surge is big risk               news           ttkciar 2023-01-15 17:25:12
```

As we can see here, the dates are not between the specified dates.

I thought the problem is that maybe I am not converting the date properly, so I looked at the raw UTC dates :

```
> final_result$created_utc
  [1] 1675096041 1676767923 1673803512 1671022066 1674220458
```

But these dates do not seem to correspond to the dates I wanted in March 2020 (https://www.epochconverter.com/).

**Am I not writing the dates correctly - can someone please show me how to fix this?**

Thanks!

Comment: Your link to the reddit api defines the use of `after` and `before` as: *"after / before - only one should be specified. these indicate the fullname of an item in the listing to use as the anchor point of the slice."* So in two ways, you are not meeting the definition of the API: you're using them both, and you're passing it a value that is not what they expect it to be.

Comment: But it seems apparent that they can interpret your epoch time frame to mean something, and (1) it can be meaningful in the other context, and (2) they apparently tell you that you should only specify one but they don't enforce that rule. Stiff-arming the lack of enforcement, I think you should assume that making a query that violates their prerequisites will categorically not return (or _reliably_ return) what you expect it to. I have no experience with the reddit api, so I can't provide the correct answer, but I suggest you need to find another way in their docs to find things by time.

Comment: @ r2evans: thank you for your reply! I will try to incorporate your suggestions!

Comment: @ r2evans: I posted some older code I was using for the Pushshift Reddit API (informal version)

Comment: So ... because pushshift implements `before`/`after` as time-based arguments in their api, you are expecting reddit to support the same thing?

Comment: @ r2evans: thank you for your reply! I am not expecting per say, I am just trying to learn how both of these APIs work. I would have thought that since the Pushshift API allows this - perhaps the actual Reddit API might allow a similar thing? sorry for my ignorance - thank you!

Comment: *Once you've seen one API, you've seen **one**.* Unless an API explicitly says that it implements features from another API, there are no suggestions that there is any commonality in end points, arguments, options, constraints, or anything else.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this at the end? I am trying to get new posts after certain date. Any hint would be appreciated. Thank you in advance and regards

Answer (score 2):

Try converting the start and end strings to their Unix timestamps with the `as.character()` function:

```
# Set start and end times
start_time <- as.character(as.POSIXct("2020-03-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC"))
end_time <- as.character(as.POSIXct("2020-03-02 23:59:59", tz = "UTC"))
```